# How to pass a string from one process to another?

Tags: c#, process

There is a process in my case which starts another process and subscribes to the Exited event.
The second process at the end should pass an error string somehow to the first process. The first process will display the message on the screen.

How to pass a string at the end of application in such a way that another app would be able to read the string and display it?

Comment: Using a file might be the simplest approach.

Comment: Or a queue.  Perhaps MSMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the StandardError stream:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("net ","use "+ args[0]);

myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();

StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardError;
// Read the standard error of net.exe and write it on to console.
Console.WriteLine( myStreamReader.ReadLine());
myProcess.Close();
```

Research the following, and pick the one that suites your needs best for your scenario.  My guess is that you either need Output or Error if you're passing data back to the parent process.

```
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput
StartInfo.RedirectStandardError
StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput
```

Comment: And how myProcess will convey an error? Just write a string to a console?

Comment: You can redirect more than just error, if that doesn't work for you.